# Variables of an SO(3)-invariant function (hamiltonian)

Tags: rotational-dynamics, symmetry, vectors, geometry, invariants

I am looking to reduce the dependence of a function, knowing that it satisfies some invariance constraints. Let me first formulate my question by explaining the 2-dimensional case.

Imagine I have a function (an Hamiltonian for example), that depends on two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now suppose that I know this function is invariant under $SO(2)$ transformation on its vectors:
$$
H(R(\theta)\vec{r}_1, R(\theta)\vec{r}_2) = H(\vec{r}_1, \vec{r}_2)
$$
where $R(\theta)$ is a rotation matrix.

The problem I am trying to solve is to reduce the dependence of the hamiltonian to the minimal number of variables, which should 3 instead of the 4 variables $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$.

Intuitively, I know that the transform :
$$
r_1 = \sqrt{x^2_1+y^2_1}\\
r_2 = \sqrt{x^2_2+y^2_2}\\
\phi_1 = \arctan(y_1/x_1) + \arctan(y_2/x_2) = \theta_1 + \theta_2\\
\phi_2 = \arctan(y_1/x_1) - \arctan(y_2/x_2) = \theta_1 - \theta_2
$$
will be the answer because the group action takes $\phi_1$ to $\phi_1+\theta$ and leaves the rest unchanged, which means that $H$ is independent of $\phi_1$.

**Question**: How to solve exactly the same problem for 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and with $H$ invariant with respect to $SO(3)$.

**Bonus**: Is there a natural generalization to higher dimensions?

Comment: Intuitively one should expect that $H$ is a function $H(r_1,r_2,\Theta)$ where $\Theta$ is the relative angle between the two vectors defined by $\mathbf{r}_1 \cdot \mathbf{r}_{2} = r_1 \; r_2\; \cos\Theta$. Your question is asking for a formal proof of this fact?

Comment: @Greg.Paul The question actually asks about three vectors, so you would probably need the three relative angles (or perhaps more simply, the three dot products).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a triangular pyramid, a tetrahedron. When you rotate it in space, it does not alter. The three vectors you are given, $\vec r_1, \vec r_2, \vec r_3$, are the edges with an ant on them.

[image]

It should be evident that you may completely characterize the solid by the length of three anted edges, and the three angles of the corresponding faces; 6 variables in all: $r_1,r_2,r_3,\vec r_1\cdot \vec r_2,\vec r_2\cdot \vec r_3, \vec r_3\cdot \vec r_1 $.

Alternatively, by the lengths of all 6 edges, $\vec r_1, \vec r_2, \vec r_3,\vec r_1- \vec r_2, \vec r_2 -\vec r_3, \vec r_3- \vec r_1$. You may see that the 6 lengths involved allow you to determine the three cosines of the angles above instead. So 6 lengths are equivalent to 3 lengths and 3 angles.

*Bonus*: Assuming you add a new vector for each dimension, you note that in 4 dimensions you have 4 vectors and 6 angles, so 10 d.o.f.s. Consequently, *mutatis mutandis*, in *d* dimensions, you have *d* vectors and ${d\choose 2}=d(d-1)/2  $ angles, so $d(d+1)/2$ d.o.f.s in all...